# What would "in modern colourless use" mean in a dictionary definition?

Tags: dictionaries

While looking up the various senses of "while" in the Oxford English Dictionary, I came across the following:

> [B 2 c.] In modern colourless use: At the same time that, besides that, in addition to the fact that; often = and at the same time, and besides.

http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/228336

I'm not sure what is implied by "colourless use" here.

Comment: Well, the sense listed could contrast with an earlier, more playful or *colorful* use. But what would a colorful use of "while" look like?!

Comment: I think they just mean that sense B2c doesn't have the explicitly *contrastive* implications of the one immediately before it, which talks about those "coloured" usages as being made up of two sub-categories (*adversatively* and *concessively*).

Comment: It's synonymous with or at least analogous to (though probably less in degree) the term 'bleached [of meaning]' (eg 'take' in 'take a bath' as opposed to 'take' in 'take your umbrella').

Comment: Does that mean that when 'while' means 'although' or 'but', it is coloured; but when 'while' means 'coincident', it is bleached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, 'colourless' is used figuratively to mean 'impartial, neutral':

> **colourless | colorless**, *adj.*
>   **3.** *fig.* Conveying no bias or inclination toward any party, view, etc.; **impartial, neutral**.

Thus, 'while' in this definition refers to the transferred sense of 'while' (see definition 2c), but without implications of

- 'provided that'
- 'if only'
- opposition
- contrast

Those implications 'color' (that is, 'supply nuances of the sense of')  the word in other transferred senses: see definitions and accompanying quotes 2a and 2b.